# I am trying to find the distinct element in an Array, but unable to understand the logic behind comparing i==j in the outer for loop. Please suggest

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class DistinctElement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = {10,10,20,30,10,20,40,30,60,100,10};

        int count=0;

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

            int j;
            for(j=0;j<i;j++){     // here we are comparing i with previous values of j
                if(arr[i] == arr[j]) {  // breaking out of loop if match
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i==j) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

I tried to debug the code but it actually didn't helped me in understanding the logic. Please suggest.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

Comment: the query is not related to the flow, rather than the logic. I am unable to get the logic here why we are comparing i==j to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Think about how you would do this manually on paper. I suggest that you do this -- draw a picture of the array on paper and then make two smaller pieces with `i` and `j` on it that you can move along the paper to point at the elements.  Then, slowly follow the code manually.

You might put one finger (`i`) on the `10` and then your other finger (`j`) on that `10` too (just to start).

Both `i` and `j` are 0 at this point.

So, it never goes into the inner loop (because `j<i` is false).

**Now, it checks if `i` and `j` are equal (they are), this means that the number under your fingers is unique, so it prints it.**

Now, we go to the outer loop and the `i` finger is on the second `10` (at index 1).  `j` starts at 0 again.

In the loop, `arr[i] == arr[j]` (they are both 10), but they are not the same index. This means that the second 10 is not unique

**So, when we break out (`i=1`, `j=0`) -- we don't go into the if and print 10 again.**

And, so on...